# Castle Windsor - DefaultInterface when Resolving

Tags: vb.net, dependencies, castle-windsor, code-injection, castle

I've only just started using Castle Windsor recently and have a question.

Suppose I have an interface- IService - and I have five classes that implement it (IServiceOne, IServiceTwo, IServiceThree) and so on.

From there I have classes that implmenent each of the IServices. They are appropriately named as ServiceOneProvider, ServiceTwoProvider, ServiceThreeProvider etc. Within these classes I am resolving an IService object.

So what I want to know is - Is it possible to have that IService object resolved using the equivalent of DefaultInterfaces (which can be used during registration) such that ServiceOneProvider will get a ServiceOne object, a ServiceTwoProvider will get a ServiceTwo object and so on?

Thanks,

-Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see anything built in to Windsor to do something like that.  I though about a HandlerSelector, but when the selector is running, you don't know the type that is requesting the dependency so that wouldn't help.

You could use the [TypedFactoryFacility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx). Just create an interface to return your IService objects (C# version):

```
public interface IProviderFactory
{
    IService GetServiceOne();
    IService GetServiceTwo();
    IService GetServiceThree();
}
```

Then name your IService instances as "ServiceOne", "ServiceTwo", etc...

```
Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<ServiceOne>().Named("ServiceOne"),
Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<ServiceTwo>().Named("ServiceTwo"),
Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<ServiceThree>().Named("ServiceThree"),
```

Then make your providers dependent on the factory and call the appropriate "Get" method:

```
public class ServiceOneProvider
{
    public ServiceOneProvider(IProviderFactory factory)
    {
        var service = factory.GetServiceOne();
    }
}

public class ServiceTwoProvider
{
    public ServiceTwoProvider(IProviderFactory factory)
    {
        var service = factory.GetServiceTwo();
    }
}

public class ServiceThreeProvider
{
    public ServiceThreeProvider(IProviderFactory factory)
    {
        var service = factory.GetServiceThree();
    }
}
```